# Installation error of slidifyLibraries from github

Tags: r, rstudio, slidify

I installed slidify following instructions from [here](http://ramnathv.github.com/slidify/start.html). I installed the windows binaries and started a slidify.rmd file successfully, but I could not install the slidifyLibraries, which makes the build crash. This is the error that follows:

```
* checking for file 'C:\Users\Roger\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpYrHr6k\ramnathv-slidifyLibraries-8e8e781/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'slidifyLibraries':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* building 'slidifyLibraries_0.1.tar.gz'
 ERROR
packaging into .tar.gz failed
Error: Command failed (1)
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:/NEWPRO~1/R-215~1.2/bin/x64/R" --vanilla CMD build "C:\Users\Roger\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpYrHr6k\ramnathv-slidifyLibraries-8e8e781" --no-manual --no-resave-data' had status 1
```

When installing Rtools I was directed to install them directly from [cran](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools), which I did. This is the session info:

```
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] slidify_0.3.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.0   evaluate_0.4.3 formatR_0.7   
[4] knitr_0.9      markdown_0.5.3 stringr_0.6.2 
[7] tools_2.15.2   whisker_0.1    yaml_2.1.5
```

Comment: Can you provide your `sessionInfo()`? Have you installed packages from source using `devtools` before? Do you have Rtools installed?

Comment: @Ramnath, I updated my query with the session info. Thanks for your reply